# Can $.connection.start() cause any trouble when a started connection already exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

As you know, in SignalR we use this client code to start the connection:

```
$.connection.hub.start()
```

Is it OK if this command is called more than once? Assume I have this code in document ready function inside _Layout.cshtml. Each time I navigate to a page or reload the existing one, that same piece of code will be fired. Does this have any negative impact on the way SignalR works?

Comment: "Each time I navigate to a page or reload the existing one" - each time that happens, you're starting again from scratch, so far as SignalR is concerned.

Comment: See [SignalR: How to stop creating new connection on page reload](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20233849/15498) where the answer starts "Each connection only has a lifecycle for the duration of the time the user spends on a given page. "

Comment: Hmmm, so I should and I did it right to put it somewhere that's available to all pages. At least those who need connection.